# Is it possible to use Stripe with only backend?

Tags: stripe-payments

I have case can't use stripe at frontend, so just wondering, if is possible to do it all in backend?

Comment: It's difficult to imagine a scenario where this would be the preferred route for Stripe specifically - can you edit your question to elaborate a bit more on the reason for the seemingly arbitrary requirement that you "*can't use stripe at frontend*"?

Comment: if you ever heard wechat, Inside 'Wechat miniprogram', they dont like any payment method expect 'wechat pay'. but the project need to be deploy to this 'miniprogram', and  client want multi payment method not only wechat pay

Comment: While tangential to the question as you've posed it, I would encourage you to re-think this requirement, as vendors will usually have *very* strong preferences to their own payment providers for a reason. This will likely get you in some considerable trouble with WeChat and all your work will be for nothing once they blacklist your mini program or even your client from publishing on their platform again.

Comment: @esqew Good call, i should check more carefully with the policy, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on exactly what you mean, but yes, it's possible but not recommended. You need to be aware of additional PCI compliance implications ([docs](https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#validating-pci-compliance) - see "API Direct" tab) and you'll run into issues with cardholder authentication for [SCA](https://stripe.com/docs/strong-customer-authentication) in regions where that is required.